# Invalid translation language (fa) specified

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I'm trying to add "fa" language in a Drupal 8 installation. I added it from admin/config/regional/language. Everything is OK and the language added successfully and added in language switcher in front-end. But when I click on it, I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Invalid translation language (fa) specified. in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->getTranslation() (line 748 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php).
```

Note: This is not a clean installation. The Drupal I have is a working site with some modules which I want to add Persian as its 6th language. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: This happened for me and was caused by Inline Entity Form for a field using referenced entities. Changing it to Autocomplete fixes it, and Entity Browser should be fine too. (Was attempting to translate from EN->DE, and the field was referencing a FI node with no EN translation.) The next lines in the traceback points the finger at IEF: `Drupal\inline_entity_form\TranslationHelper::prepareEntity(Object, Object) (Line: 338)`
`Drupal\inline_entity_form\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\InlineEntityFormBase->prepareFormState(Object, Object, 1) (Line: 215)`
`Drupal\inline_entity_form\Plugin\Field\Fie...`

Comment: Reported to IEF here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2908780

Answer (score 6):

Basically, this error appears when some translation methods like $entity->getTranslation('LANGUAGE_CODE') or $entity->addTranslation('LANGUAGE_CODE') are called and there is no translation of the entity in the specified language.

The solution is to check if the entity hasTranslation using **$entity->hasTranslation('fa')** before calling the getTranslation or addTranslation like this:

```
if ($entity->hasTranslation('fa')) {
  $translation = $entity->getTranslation('fa');
}
```